# Re-compile JSON data to make less rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, chart.js

If I have a JSON result that has many rows, sometimes up to 100

Label:Part1    Value:1000
Label:Part2    Value:700
Label:Part3    Value:600
Label:Part4    Value:500

... and so on

I would like to change the data so that it lists the top 5 results as normal, but instead of listing the rest, it sums the value and changes the label to 'others'.

Example

Label:Part1    Value:1000
Label:Part2    Value:700
Label:Part3    Value:600
Label:Part4    Value:500
Label:Part5    Value:500
Label:other    Value:25650

Is this possible to do in javascript, before I pass to a chart.js pie? Or is there a better method to achieve this?

Current code for pie

```
function chart1(branch, apitime){           
            $.ajax({
           url: jsonpath' + apitime + branch,
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           success: function (response) {
                console.log (response);
                var datachart = response;
                var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext("2d");
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(datachart);
           }
        });
    }
```

Data is sorted and I could change the SQL on the server to do this also, I just don't know what the correct method is to do that.

JSON example here http://pastebin.com/p3Y9mSX3

Comment: It'll be better to do it in JavaScript. Do you a fiddle with your data set up?

Comment: No, but I added the function I am using. The data is just simple JSON with 2 bits of data per row. Label & value

Comment: @potatopeelings surely the processing should be done on the server side ? Let the backend handle the grunt work.. ?

Comment: Can you show your JSON data?

Comment: @Pogrindis - I think it would be better to do it on the client side (because if you have the actual smaller values you could show them in a table). But I may be biased because I've seen it done that way on one other charting library (g.raphael). Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your data just before creating the chart.

```
var top6 = datachart.slice(0,5)
top6[5] = {
    label: 'other',
    value: datachart.slice(5).reduce(function(sum, data) {
      return sum + data.value
    }, 0)
}
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(top6);
```

This can be made more general to get the top N entries

```
var getTopN = function(dataArray, n)
  var tops = dataArray.slice(0, n)
  tops[n] = {
    label: 'other',
    value: dataArray.slice(n).reduce(function(sum, data) {
      return sum + data.value
    }, 0)
  }
  return tops
}  

var top5 = getTopN(datachart, 5) 
var top10 = getTopN(datachart, 10)
```